# $this->db->where('field !=', 1); when default is null in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

when i use
     $this->db->where('field !=', 1);

i want to select all entries where field is not 1.  so that means here 0 or NULL
however in codeigniter he doesn't select it where the entry is NULL (default value).

how to solve this without changing the database?

dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL values need to be handled separately with another `where` clause:

```
$this->db->where('field <>', 1)->or_where('field IS NULL', NULL);
```

It has nothing to do with Codeigniter. It's a MySQL matter.

Comment: thanks! actually had to do it this way $this->db->where("(field != 1 OR field IS NULL)"); because of the OR. there should be a cleaner way in codeigniter but don't think there is one.